# How can i get specific interwiki link of a category by my programme?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

This is my programme which get all the interwiki links (cotains many `li` tags). But i want to get only a specific language `li`tag which is as follows.

```
<li class="interlanguage-link interwiki-ta"> ...title= </li>
```

How can i get the data after the specific `title=` ?

How can i complete my code as follows;-

command: `python3 get-tamiwiki-link-from-englishwiki.py`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:proprietary software'   
content = requests.get(url).content 
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml') 
#to get all the li tag 
interwikihead = soup.find(id='p-lang') 
print(interwikihead) 
#print(interwikihead.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
# li class="interlanguage-link interwiki-ta"
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:proprietary software'
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
#to get all the li tag
interwikihead = soup.find('li', class_="interlanguage-link interwiki-ta")
print(interwikihead.text)
try:
    title = interwikihead.a.get('title')
    print(title)
except:
    print('title no find')
```

out:

```
தமிழ்

பகுப்பு:தனியுடைமை மென்பொருட்கள் – Tamil
```

Comment: Great. if there is no output in Tamil, how can avoid error message.

Comment: what is Tamil?  ?

Comment: Tamil is a language. See your output, that is Tamil. ta is Tamil's iso code in wikimedia. So, we coded for "interlanguage-link interwiki-ta" as soup.find.